# Why DataInputStream.readUTF() causing Main Thread to wait forever ? [Socket Programming]

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, datainputstream

I've got a little Socket Server that written in Java. My application basically reads data from Socket and writes it to the Output. Anyway when i'm trying to read data from Socket with `readUTF()` function it's just causing Main Thread to wait and then gives EOFException at the second connection but **if i use `DataInputStream.readLine()` function it's working.**

My code with `readUTF()` :

```
private static PrintStream console = System.out;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5112);
    console.println("Server Started !");
    while(true){
        console.println("Loop");
        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

        console.println("Processing Request");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        console.println("Proccessing in");
        console.println("Available : " + in.available());
        console.println("Request Body : \n");
        String str = in.readUTF(in);
        console.println(str);
        console.println("Waiting for new !");
    }
}
```

And the output is :

`Server Started !
Loop
Processing Request
Proccessing in
Available : 0
Request Body :`

Answer (score 2):

`readUTF()` reads binary encoded stream, not text data. Therefore the code expects probably thousands of characters due to the encoding.

See [`readUTF()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF()) documentation.